# In Django is it better to get a list of objects from self and use related names or from the object itself and use filter?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

The title is probably confusing but I didn't know how else to paraphrase it. Here is an example.

Is it better to do something like this

```
class UserType( models.Model ) :
    def user_count( self ) :
        return self.userprofile_set.count()
```

or like this?

```
class UserType( models.Model ) :
    def user_count( self ) :
        # Does "user_types = self" work? I'm not sure.
        return UserProfile.filter( user_types = self.pk ).count()
```

where

```
class UserProfile( models.Model ) :
    user_types = models.ManyToManyField( UserType )
```

`UserType.user_count()` simply returns the number of `UserProfile` who has a particular `UserType`.

Sorry if this is a stupid, trivial question, but I was curious. Perhaps some Django expert can dig in on the actual SQL performance or something :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same. Choose whatever you like.

In my opinion the first looks cleaner. The second seems a bit incorrect because user_types is not a single pk value.

By the way, it is recommended to always specify a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute.

For example if it would be:

```
user_types = models.ManyToManyField(UserType, related_name='profiles')
```

and then:

```
return self.profiles.count()
```

Looks even cleaner.

But both statements generate the same sql, we just could say that first is the shortcut for second. So it's not about sql-performance